# Python, Pandas сумма данной ячейки и ячеек, находящихся выше данной

Tags: python, pandas

У меня есть таблица с тремя столбцами "Data", "Puck" (в "Puck" разность между забитыми и пропущенными по дням шайбам, естественно если больше пропускали, то число отрицательное). Таблица отсортирована по датам по возрастанию, меня интересует, как я могу найти сумму самой ячейки в столбце "Puck" со всеми остальными, стоящими выше данной (сумма всего столбца мне не нужна). Т.е. мне нужно получить такую же таблицу, только в столбце "Puck" будет разность не в определенный день, а в сравнении с предыдущими (в первый день забито на 3 больше, чем пропущено - разность 3, на второй день пропустили на 2 больше, чем забили - итого разность 1 и т.д.). Если мы будем переписывать данные в этой же таблице поочередно перебирая ячейки, то можно просто находить сумму данной и предыдущей, но я не совсем понимаю как это осуществить. Заранее спасибо за помощь.

исходные данные

| Data | Puck |
| --- | --- |
| 2008-09-03 | -1 |
| 2008-09-05 | -2 |
| 2008-09-07 | 1 |
| 2008-09-11 | 4 |
| 2008-09-13 | -1 |
| 2008-09-15 | -1 |

желаемый результат

| Data | Puck |
| --- | --- |
| 2008-09-03 | -1 |
| 2008-09-05 | -3 |
| 2008-09-07 | -2 |
| 2008-09-11 | 2 |
| 2008-09-13 | 1 |
| 2008-09-15 | 0 |

Comment: пример исходных данных и желаемого результата должен быть в вопросе в воспроизводимом (текстовом) виде.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

я так понимаю, речь идет о кумулятивной сумме...
имеем датасет:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(108)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(-3, 5, size=10), index = pd.date_range(start="2022-01-01", end="2022-01-10", freq="D"), columns=["Puck"])
```

```
            Puck
2022-01-01     0
2022-01-02     4
2022-01-03    -2
2022-01-04     0
2022-01-05     3
2022-01-06     3
2022-01-07    -1
2022-01-08     1
2022-01-09    -1
2022-01-10    -2
```

далее делаем простую агрегацию:

```
df["new"] = df["Puck"].cumsum()
```

получаем df:

```
            Puck  new
2022-01-01     0    0
2022-01-02     4    4
2022-01-03    -2    2
2022-01-04     0    2
2022-01-05     3    5
2022-01-06     3    8
2022-01-07    -1    7
2022-01-08     1    8
2022-01-09    -1    7
2022-01-10    -2    5
```

Comment: Спасибо! помогло